# Specify an attribute value using the parent selector in LESS?

Tags: css-selectors, less

Is is possible to use the parent selector in LESS to specify a value for a parent attribute selector?

I want the following output:

```
[some-attribute] {
    font-weight: normal;
}

[some-attribute~="bold"] {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Given this (obviously incorrect) example:

```
[some-attribute] {
    font-weight: normal;

    &~="bold" {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

Is something like this possible in LESS?

**EDIT:** For anyone who might be curious, I did try this abomination:

```
[some-attribute {

    &] {
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    &~="bold"] {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

I'm kind of glad it didn't work. I might have been tempted.

Comment: Are you using LESS or Sass?  You have to pick one.  A LESS solution is dramatically different from a Sass solution.

Comment: @cimmanon I use LESS and SCSS regularly on a variety of projects. I'm curious about solutions for both.

Comment: Using both tags makes it rather difficult to close as a duplicate, since a Sass version of this question already exists:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400162/how-can-i-add-additional-information-to-an-attribute-selector-via-nesting-in-sas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent selector (`&`) only holds a reference to an entire complex selector, with the option to extend the selector provided that you use the entire thing as a base:

```
.one > .two {
    &::after, &::before {
        // Compiles to .one > .two::after, .one > .two::before
    }
    & + .three {
        // Compiles to .one > .two + .three

        &-suffix {
            // Compiles to .one > .two + .three-suffix
        }
    }
}
```

It cannot be used to reference a part of a compound or simple selector, in particular it cannot be used to reference just the attribute name in an attribute selector. You'll have to stick with vanilla CSS.

The reason that abomination doesn't work is because both preprocessors expect all selectors in style rules to be valid; `[some-attribute` is not a valid selector. You could [write a mixin and/or use selector interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610566/specify-an-attribute-value-using-the-parent-selector-in-less-scss/30610867#30610867), but it still has to result in a valid selector when used with a style rule, since the compiler can't assume that you won't be using the selector in its own set of style declarations (though of course, whether a preprocessor *should* be controlling the author in this way is up for debate...).

Comment: +1 - Yeah, good point. I hadn't considered longer selectors (how could it know where I want my attribute value stuffed into?).

Answer (score 3):

> Disclaimer: This is strictly how not to over-complicate things but yeah it is still possible in a way using selector interpolation and mixins.

You could write a mixin like below which makes use of the attribute name as one input parameter and the condition as another. The condition is an optional parameter and when it is not provided, the mixin considers it as only a attribute presence selector.

The rules that have to be attached are also passed as input.

```css
.mixin-attrib-selector(@attr-name, @rule, @param:null){
    @sel-start: ~"[";
    @sel-end: ~"]";
    @{sel-start}@{attr-name}{
        & when(@param = null){
            &@{sel-end}{
                @rule();
            }
        }
        & when not (@param = null){
            &@{param}@{sel-end}{
                @rule();
            }
        }
    }
}

.mixin-attrib-selector(some-attribute, {
            font-weight: normal;
        });
.mixin-attrib-selector(some-attribute,{
            font-weight: bold;
        }, ~"~='bold'");

#output{
    .mixin-attrib-selector(some-attr, {
                font-weight: normal;
            });
    .mixin-attrib-selector(some-attr,{
                font-weight: italic;
            }, ~"~='italic'");
}
```

Comment: (Not to say this is a *bad* answer, the "bad" refers to the sheer overkill of it ;)

Comment: @BoltClock: No worries mate. I understood what you meant. I hope nobody puts this answer to use but just wanted to show how unnecessary complexity it adds :)

Comment: +1 - This is sheer brilliance! Thank you for solving my issue! I'm going to put this into production tonight!

Comment: @BryanDowning: Be ultra careful with production implementation mate. This works but is not something that I myself would prefer to use.

Comment: Nonsense. In production, anything goes ;)

Comment: Yeah, no way man. I want to mark this as the accepted answer, but I'm afraid someone might actually use it. Seriously, though - very cool. Way to make it fit.

Comment: @BryanDowning: I am glad you did not accept it mate.

Answer (score 2):

No way that I know of. The closest thing you can do is

```
[some-attribute] {
    font-weight: normal;

    &[some-attribute~="bold"] {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

which outputs

```
[some-attribute] {
  font-weight: normal;
}

[some-attribute][some-attribute~="bold"] {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

but you're better off keeping them separate

```
[some-attribute] {
    font-weight: normal;
}

[some-attribute~="bold"] {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: +1 - Yeah, this is what I've been doing for a while. I usually keep them separate to avoid specificity issues. I really like the whole AMCSS idea, but the CSS is a bit nasty.

Comment: @Bryan Downing: That's the first time I've heard about AMCSS. Surprised it hasn't yet been shot down by performance junkies on the sole basis that attribute selectors are slower than class selectors ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ (let alone more typing as you suggest)

Comment: @BoltClock - haha, there's still plenty of time for all that. Even though the CSS is messier, I think it can really improve working with the HTML, and in my experience, most devs would rather not touch the CSS anyway.