# Simplifying sass attribute selectors

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I'm trying to come up with a way to simplify some SCSS attribute selectors.  What I end up with is:

```
[data-attr="opt1"] { ... }
[data-attr="opt2"] { ... }
[data-attr="opt3"] { ... }
```

What I'm hoping for is to be able to write something closer to:

```
[data-attr]
    &="opt1" { ... }
    &="opt2" { ... }
    &="opt3" { ... }
```

via a mixin, or whatever.  Can't come up with a solution though.  Any clever ideas?

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400162/how-can-i-add-additional-information-to-an-attribute-selector-via-nesting-in-sas

Comment: @cimmanon -- this is not a dupe of that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to this idea:

```
@mixin attrVal($value) {
    $attr: str-slice(#{&}, 2, -2); // $attr = "data-attr"
    @at-root { 
        [#{$attr}="#{$value}"] {
           @content; 
        }
    } 
}

[data-attr] {
    @include attrVal('opt1') { width: 10px; }
    @include attrVal('opt2') { width: 20px; }
    @include attrVal('opt3') { width: 30px; }
}
```

---

Output (tested on sassmeister.com)

```
[data-attr="opt1"] { width: 10px; }
[data-attr="opt2"] { width: 20px; }
[data-attr="opt3"] { width: 30px; }
```

For this specific example there's no that huge simplification, but with this approach you're actually decoupling the attribute name from its value (in the aim of code reuse).