# Target attribute values in SASS

Tags: html, css, sass, attributes

I use attribute modules in my HTML and SASS because it's very logical. Currently, I may have markup like this:

```
<article data-post="wrap feature">
  <h1 data-post="title feature">Feature title</h1>
</article>

<article data-post="wrap">
  <h1 data-post="title">Normal title</h1>
</article>
```

The SASS would look something like this:

```
[data-post] {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black; }

[data-post~="title"] {
  font-size: 20px; }

[data-post~="title"][data-post~="feature"] {
  font-size: 30px; }
```

Works fine, but I'm wondering if it's possible in SASS to nest these. They all apply to the `[data-post]` so I want to target attributes within that. I'm imagining something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
[data-post] {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;

  &[~="title"] {
    font-size: 20px; }

  &[~="title"]&[~="feature"] {
    font-size: 30px; }
}
```

This would be more logical, more DRY and easier to code/maintain.

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400162/how-can-i-add-additional-information-to-an-attribute-selector-via-nesting-in-sas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is close. You will have to restate the attribute name in your child selectors each time. Classes and IDs can get away with [tacking on an ending to the parent class](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector), but if you extend the same idea to your attribute your second selector would be `[data-post][~="title"]`.

So:

```
[data-post] {
  font-size: 10px;

  &[data-post~="title"] {
    font-size: 50px;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

That should get you there. http://jsbin.com/kazusamore/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Yeh, the problem here is it's not very DRY. Once this gets extended to have values for lots of elements such as title, description, link, image, it will have the attribute stated loads of times.

Comment: Maybe, but it's the way Sass works. Ultimately I think you'd be better served using classes for this kind of thing anyway. The example seems like it'd be better done that way, but I answered the question as given assuming you have good reason. You could nest and extend classes like you're trying to do with attributes easily and more DRY.

The question this is marked as a duplicate of has a more complex method to do what you're asking if that's what you really need to do.

Comment: Yeh fair play. I might change to classes. I was essentially looking to mix the BEM methodology of classes and extensions, with attribute modules for more semantic markup.